# PingFederate: SP SLO vs. IDP SLO - Does it really matter?

Tags: single-sign-on, saml-2.0, pingfederate

The [PingFederate documentation](http://documentation.pingidentity.com/display/PF/Specifying+SLO+Service+URLs+%28SAML+2.0%29) notes that you may configure *either* SP or IDP single-log-out (a.k.a. SLO).

A user initiates SLO when that user requests a "Start-SLO" endpoint from their browser (i.e. either `http://<PingFederate Base URL>/sp/startSSO.ping` or `http://<PingFederate Base URL>/idp/startSSO.ping`).

My Questions:

- Isn't this just a distinction *in name only*?
- At the end of the day, aren't we just targeting an endpoint anyway?
- Does this choice have any material impact on the SLO process?

---

@Scott T. had the following to say [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8236928/109941):

> If users start the SLO process at the IdP, then yes - users will be
>   redirected back to /idp/SLO.saml2 as the last step. In fact, each SP
>   that you redirect to for logout, will redirect back to the IdP to
>   logout of the next SP. **If you start the SLO process from an SP, then
>   the last place users will end up is at that SP's SLO endpoint.**

Indeed, it would be nice if PingFederate redirected to the SP that initated the SLO as the last step, but this hasn't been my experience.

Perhaps I should also ask:

- How do you specify the SP that initated the SLO?

---

**EDIT:** Per @Scott T.'s answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8276361/109941):

> I'm assuming here you have PingFederate as an IdP and SP (potentially
>   2 separate installs).

As I understand the definitions of IdP and SP:

- PingFederate is ***neither*** my IdP **nor** one of my SPs.**
- For my configuration, PingFederate merely facilitates the open token transfer *between* my IdP and my SP.
- Until very recently, I was of the belief that this was a completely valid configuration.
- But now it seems like this configuration doesn't facilitate SLO; or at least as nicely as it would if PingFederate was acting as my IdP.

  - Is this correct?

**When I say this, I mean to say that I have:

- A standalone web application which authenticates users, and has a backing store (i.e. a database) that includes user names and passwords - **This acts as my IdP.**
- Multiple standalone web applications which are linked to my IdP which display data and provide functionality to my users - **These act as my SPs.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming here you have PingFederate as an IdP and SP (potentially 2 separate installs).  If you want to start the SLO process from your IdP, you would request it at: http://pingfed-idp/idp/startSSO.ping.  If you want to star the SLO process from your SP, you would request it at: http://pingfed-sp/sp/startSSO.ping.

There is a slight difference in flow from either model:

If you start at IdP, then the IdP will send a SAML 2.0 LogoutRequest message to each of the SP's (one at a time) where you have an SSO session.  Each SP will logout the user from the local session, then redirect back to the SP with a SAML LogoutResponse saying success/fail.  The process ends at the IdP once the final SP is done.

If you start at the SP, then that SP will send a SAML 2.0 LogoutRequest to the IdP, then the IdP sends a LogoutRequest to every other SP (one at a time) where you have an SSO session.  Each SP will again logout the user from the local session, then redirect back to the SP with a SAML LogoutResponse saying success/fail.  Once the IdP is done terminating all sessions - it sends a final LogoutResponse to the original SP that initiated SLO.

Comment: You are right in saying your applications implement the real SP / IdP role.  However, I would expect PingFederate is doing more than simply passing around OpenTokens.  Isn't it the one generating SAML request / responses?  Don't you have connection configuration in PingFederate Administration for SP / IdP role?  PingFederate always works in conjunction with adapters & connection configuration to implement the "first mile" (IdP) and "last mile" (SP) of federation integration.