# SAML2 Single Logout, where to post responses to?

Tags: single-sign-on, saml, saml-2.0

I'm a bit confused as to where Requests/Responses go within SAML2 single logout.

For single sign on, there is an endpoint on the IDP to receive requests and an endpoint on the SP to receive responses. So each end point only servers one purpose.

However, single logout can be both SP and IDP triggered, but I always see only 1 endpoint defined with IDPs and SPs. Does this mean that both Requests and Responses have to go to the same endpoint? And thus, to know whether it's a request or response, the IDP or SP needs to look at the XML it receives?

Comment: I've opened similar question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47982791/saml-2-0-singlelogoutresponse-endpoint
Can u share some light if u can? thanks

Answer (score 4):

There is a so-called `Single Logout profile` in SAML 2.0 standard [doc reference](https://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-profiles-2.0-os.pdf).

In `4.4 Single Logout Profile` on Page 32, it details the flow as below:

1. `<LogoutRequest>` issued by Session Participant to Identity Provider
2. Identity Provider determines Session Participants
3. `<LogoutRequest>` issued by Identity Provider to Session Participant/Authority
4. Session Participant/Authority issues `<LogoutResponse>` to Identity Provider
5. Identity Provider issues `<LogoutResponse>` to Session Participant

The basic flow for SLO shows below:
[image: Basic flow for SLO]

As more detailed in [PingFederate SLO implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8276361/791609), and [PortalGuard article](https://www.portalguard.com/blog/2016/06/20/saml-single-logout-need-to-know/), you can see the difference between SP-initiated SLO and IdP-initiated SLO is just who issued the `<LogoutRequest>` and after receiving `<LogoutResponse>`, who is responsible to show the logout page to the end-user.

Hope this answers your concern.

Comment: Thanks, but that is basically already in the question. My question was whether the logout requests and responses both go the the 'single logout service' endpoint. 

The document you linked talks a little bit about this:
`The same or different endpoints MAY be used for requests and responses.`

But does that mean you can specify which endpoint to use for requests and which for responses? And if so, how?

Comment: My understanding of that line is, if you have one federation server acting as both IdP and SP, then the SLO endpoint would be the same. Otherwise, if it is heterogeneous deployment, then the endpoint would be different. Also, SLO endpoint is also a metadata for SSO setup.

Comment: Yes, but then what is the SLO endpoint in the metadata?
AFAIK, the saml spec only mentions: 'SingleLogoutService'. So if you have in your metadata: `<md:SingleLogoutService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect" Location="https://example.com/slo"/>` is that used for both requests AND responses? And is it then up to the endpoint to inspect the XML and determine what is being send?

Comment: @Seba, Yes, depending which role you have, the `<SingleLogoutService>` will get specified under either `<IDPSSODescriptor>` or `<SPSSODescriptor>`.